# SQL: n to m relationship in a database with relations inbetween one table

Tags: sql, database, relationship, intersection

When talking about n to m relationships in a database, an intersection table is often mentioned. 
E.g. there are authours and books, an author can have a relationship to many books and vice versa.

But: How can I model the relationship, that the authors can also have relationships among them and books, too?

E.g. 
- Author A has written Book 1 and Book 2, and Author A is a friend of Author B. 
- Book 1 is related to the same genre as Book 2.

Do I have multiple Intersection tables then? 
E.g. An Author - Book Relationship table, an Author -Author "Friend"-Relationship table and a Book-Book "Genre" Relationship?

I am a beginner concerning databases and SQL...
Thank you for your help,
Anne

Comment: Table1:Author, Table2:Book and Table3:Author_Book_Mapping

Comment: What about the Author-Author Mapping and the Book-Book-Mapping?

Comment: the author-author relation through a Book only? or do u want to directly link an author to another author(s)?

Comment: I direct link between the authors is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a simple `1:n` relation-ship, it's enough to have one `FOREIGN KEY`-column to specify the related record.

But whenever you want to model a `m:n` relationship, or you might need to add additional information to a `1:n` relationship, you'll need a mapping table.

- mapping tables with `1:n` relations: Imagine the case, that a book can have exactly one current reader. If you'd use a FK `CurrentReaderID` in the `Book` table, you would not be able to find previous readers once you've changed the FK-value.
- mapping tables with `m:n` relations: Think of the relation as an object on its own with its own specific detail data (when, validTo, createdBy...)

And yes: In a well designed database you'll find **many tables** with a **wide range of different relations / mappings** among them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is fairly standard.  If books can have multiple genres, a Book-Genre table containing Genre IDs from one side and Book Ids from the other is perfectly appropriate.  The Author-Friend relation is a bit trickier as the intersection table will join to the Author table twice (once for each author in the author-friend relation), but is essentially the same.

As you've identified, these are the same as a Book-Author table that links books to their authors on a n:m basis.

Look for student-teacher-course examples as they are similar and often part of an n:m explanation.